# Save task with a specific date and timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, time

It's a rails project. I have a form where the user can schedule tasks. For the moment I get the timezone of the browser with :

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var timezone_offset = currentTime.getTimezoneOffset()
```

And then I use it in my controller. But the problem is :

- How can I save the date to be scheduled to the right moment?

I thought the answer will be to parse the date from my form and then change the offset but it doesn't work:

```
> time  = Time.parse("2015/11/30 12:00")
=> 2015-11-30 12:00:00 +0100
> time.change(offset: '+02:00')
=> 2015-11-30 12:00:00 +0100
```

Maybe the answer is to [create a Time.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#class-Time-label-Creating+a+new+Time+instance)?

My heroku server is on UTC. Some users on CET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off getting your form to submit the time in UTC format.

Using something like `moment.js` (http://momentjs.com/) you can get their local time in the browser and display the date/time in their local format, but submit the UTC counterpart to the server when submitting your form.